# Export data from Parse to provide markers on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, parse-platform

I'm trying to pull lat and long data from a Parse database to create markers onto a map. The data is stored in a Parse database and I'm using Google Maps JS api v.3

My current code for connecting to Parse is not working;

```
//Load Markers from Parse, Check (Do we need to create a connection string)

    $.get("parse-connect.js", function (data) {
        $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
             //Get user input values for the marker from the form
              var address   = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
              var type      = $(this).attr('type');
              var point     = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('latitude')),parseFloat($(this).attr('longitude')));

              //call create_marker() function for xml loaded maker
              create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "../img/map-marker-2.png");
        });
    });
```

`"parse-connect.js"` simply calls the Parse application ID and JS api key to connect.

If anyone has any suggestions or on-line tutorials that could help my Id be very grateful.

The database has a simple structure with 4 fields - objectID, address, lat, long, image.

Comment: Your "code for connecting to Parse is not working", but that's happening in "parse-connect.js"... which you haven't included in your question.  If the problem is not being able to connect, can you show us the code that's trying to do the connection?

Comment: Apologies Duncan 'Parse.initialize("pidt6nz9C05S46ykNMXZQPunAPjIULBwnfbrjpVz", "oj994YkxqSEyquGL6xr7HpZystcqRCgQuDPJy7bv");'

Comment: what does the contents of `data` look like?

Comment: Have added fields... thought this would be easy using an API from Parse?

Comment: I'm still confused what the problem is - is it making the connection to Parse, or is it adding the markers?

Comment: Its making the connection to Parse is proving difficult - I've not used it before.